# Как сдвинуть длинную команду в терминале, при редактировании в середине/начале

Tags: c, bash, shell

В баше строка автоматически сдвигается если редактируется, неважно сколько линий терминала она занимает. Как это реализовать с помощью Си ?

Comment: использовать библиотеку readline https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html ?

Comment: @KoVadim Вы не поняли задачу, мне нужно Написать readline

Comment: не совсем понятно, что ты имеешь в виду под «строка автоматически сдвигается если редактируется»... `bash` почти наверняка делает это через `readline`... а `readline` работает через curses'овские `tputs`, `tgoto` итп, который уже с помощью `terminfo` транслируют это добро в управляющие последовательности конкретного терминала... я бы предложил посмотреть исходники всего этого, но это специфическое чтиво...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Вы всё верно поняли. Я уже неплохо разобрался и в termcap и в termios, но input mode позволяет сдвигать только в рамках одной строки( последний символ в строке пропадает в небытие)  . Я ищу  способ включить  input mode для команды в несколько строк. Топорный алгоритм - это стереть, написать заново и вернуть курсор на место - но у меня впечатление что в readline это происходит по другому. Ибо насколько бы длинной не была команда в bash и строки не мерцают и курсор не скачет.